# How to get the graphics context of an UIView?

Tags: iphone

For example, I want to draw something directly to an UIView. I need an CGContextRef, but I don't want to make a new one since that would eat up too much memory. Can I obtain the CGContextRef from an UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the redraw call, I do not believe so. I remember trying this myself a while ago. Sorry I can't be more specific, but I've not touched the iPhone SDK in months.

Comment: The application we had in the store got pulled - even though applications of the same topic from larger companies remain in the store. Our content was original, we didn't rip off anyone elses app, Apple just decided to remove us. Last time we develop anything for the iPhone, I can tell you that.

Comment: oh that really sucks. I sweared to myself if that happens I go to Android. Would be interesting to know what kind of app did you do exactly? And what did apple argue with, for taking it off the store? Did you blog about that? Would like to read more... I'm starting to think Apple seriously sucks.

Comment: If you recall a month or so ago, a lot of applications were removed with adult content. Our application was not exactly lude, not by the standards of others that have remained up there such as Playboy etc. That's all I can say - I don't really want to name names, as that's my employers job to talk about this kind of thing, provided releases etc.

100 for a dev license, and even after spending MONTHS getting the application approved, within a few months of it going live they feel free to remove it without a notice? We found out from BBC News for gods sake!

*pats his new Android phone*

Answer (score 5):

Only in the drawRect method:

`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`