# Swift UIView How to add more drawing after calling draw function ? Using UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, uibezierpath

This example I am drawing a line and I want to add an arrow on the tip of it. The arrow function works fine when I use it in draw function but it is not being added to the view when I call it later on. Is there some way for me to add it later on ?

**My BezierView Class
**

```
final class BezierView: UIView {

    var currentPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let line1 = UIBezierPath()
        line1.move(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 65))
        line1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 15))
        line1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:  self.frame.width - 20, y: 5))
        line1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - 20, y: 65))
        line1.lineWidth = 2
        UIColor.darkGray.setStroke()
        line1.stroke()
        currentPoint = line1.currentPoint
    }


    func drawArrow() {
        let point = currentPoint
        let arrowTip = UIBezierPath()
        arrowTip.move(to: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y))
        arrowTip.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x - 6, y: point.y - 6))
        arrowTip.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x + 6, y: point.y - 6))
        arrowTip.close()
        UIColor.darkGray.setFill()
        arrowTip.fill()
    }
}
```

**My View Controller
**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let bezierView = BezierView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200))
        bezierView.drawArrow()
    }
```

[image: Current Output:]

I have tried to use: self.setNeedsDisplay(), self.setNeedsLayout(), self.layoutSubviews() functions in the drawArrow function but they didn't change the outcomes.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why filling and stroking a bezier path draws things on the screen is because the `draw(_:)` method is called (by iOS) in a graphics context created by the system that allows you to draw on the screen. After `draw(_:)` returns, the graphics context ends, and you can no longer draw things on the screen.

Therefore, calling `drawArrow` in `viewDidLoad` does not work. You are not in that specific graphics context. Unfortunately, [you cannot get this graphics context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543704/how-to-get-the-graphics-context-of-an-uiview) from outside of `draw(_:)` and draw in it.

In other words, all the drawing has to be done in `draw(_:)`. If you just want to draw one arrow, you can just keep a boolean to store whether the arrow has been drawn or not:

```
final class BezierView: UIView {

    var isArrowDrawn = false {
        didSet {
            // this causes draw(_:) to be called again
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let line1 = UIBezierPath()
        line1.move(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 65))
        line1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 15))
        line1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:  self.frame.width - 20, y: 5))
        line1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - 20, y: 65))
        line1.lineWidth = 2
        UIColor.darkGray.setStroke()
        line1.stroke()
        
        if isArrowDrawn {
            let point = line1.currentPoint
            let arrowTip = UIBezierPath()
            arrowTip.move(to: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y))
            arrowTip.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x - 6, y: point.y - 6))
            arrowTip.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x + 6, y: point.y - 6))
            arrowTip.close()
            UIColor.darkGray.setFill()
            arrowTip.fill()
        }
    }


    func drawArrow() {
        isArrowDrawn = true
    }
}
```

If you want multiple arrows, to be drawn whenever `drawArrow` is called, then you would need to keep track of the list of points at which the arrows all are located. Something like

```
final class BezierView: UIView {

    var currentPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()
    
    var arrowPoints = [CGPoint]() {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // ... omitted for brevity

        currentPoint = line1.currentPoint
        for point in arrowPoints {
            let arrowTip = UIBezierPath()
            arrowTip.move(to: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y))
            arrowTip.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x - 6, y: point.y - 6))
            arrowTip.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x + 6, y: point.y - 6))
            arrowTip.close()
            UIColor.darkGray.setFill()
            arrowTip.fill()
        }
    }


    func drawArrow() {
        arrowPoints.append(currentPoint)
    }
}
```

Basically, you need to keep track of all the "states" that your view can be in, and your `draw(_:)` method is responsible for drawing the current state.

If you find this quite annoying, consider switching to using layers instead. You can, at any time, create a [`CAShapeLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer) with a path, and add it as a sublayer as `self.layer`. Here is a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@samarthpaboowal/drawing-using-cashapelayer-in-ios-9a6c83de7eb2) to get started with.